# Results of joined queries in BQ don't match data in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

**Background**

In BigQuery, I'm trying to find the number of visitors that both visit one of two pages and purchase a specific product.

When I run each of the sub-queries, the numbers match exactly what I see in Google Analytics.

However, when I join them, the number is different than what I see in GA. I've had someone bring the results of the two sub-queries into Excel and do the equivalent, and their results equal what I'm seeing in BQ.

**Details**

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
  ProductSessions.date AS date,
  SUM(ProductTransactions.totalTransactions) transactions,
  COUNT(ProductSessions.visitId) visited_product_sessions
FROM (
  SELECT
    visitId, date
  FROM 
    `103554833.ga_sessions_20170219`
  WHERE
    EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) h
      WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagePath, r"^www.domain.com/(product|product2).html.*"))
  GROUP BY visitID, date) 
  AS ProductSessions
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    totals.transactions as totalTransactions,
    visitId,
    date
  FROM
    `103554833.ga_sessions_20170219`
  WHERE
    totals.transactions IS NOT NULL
    AND EXISTS(
      SELECT 1
      FROM 
        UNNEST(hits) h,
        UNNEST(h.product) prod
      WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(prod.v2ProductName, r"^Product®$"))
  GROUP BY
    visitId, totals.transactions,
    date) AS ProductTransactions
ON
  ProductTransactions.visitId = ProductSessions.visitId
WHERE ProductTransactions.visitId is not null
GROUP BY
  date
ORDER BY
  date ASC
```

I'm expecting ProductTransactions.totalTransactions to replicate the number of transactions in Google Analytics when filtered with an advanced segment of both:

- Sessions include Page matching RegEx: www.domain.com/(product|product2).html.*
- Sessions include Product matches exactly: Product®

However, results in BG are about 20% higher than in GA.

Why the difference?

Comment: You could probably reach out to your 360 support since you are using BQ.

Comment: Are you sure the dates are actually the same? BQ and Google Analytics might display the data in different time zones.